# How to parse multiple GET parameters into URL if one unsets another?

Tags: php, url, parameters, get

Let's say, I'll have a webpage "abcde.com" with two submit buttons: "Set GET 1" and "Set GET 2".
 The "Set GET 1" button redirects user to abcde.com?first=x. The "Set GET 2" button redirects user to abcde.com?second=x. 
Both using PHP's ('Location: ?first=') and ('Location: ?second=').
If user clicks on Set GET 1, GET parameter will be set in the URL. However, if user clicks on Set GET 2 right after setting the first GET parameter, the button will redirect him to the second parameter, removing the first one from the URL.

Is it possible to achieve setting multiple GET parameters in the URL divided by & in PHP without writing `if (isset($_GET["first"])) { ('Location: ?first=x&?second=x') }`?
I mean, so it can add & and set another parameter without removing the previous one? Even though I understand that PHP redirects user to URL without previous GET parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$_GET` to store current query string in an array, append your values to it, then build the new querystring with `http_build_query`:

```
$queryArray = $_GET;
$queryArray['second']='x';
$urlWithQueryString = 'http://example.com/somepage/?' . http_build_query($queryArray);

header('Location:'.$urlWithQueryString);
```